# Pushing back to previous view deleting old data why?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have trying to push back from current view to my previuos view but while pushing back,i get my data null in destinationationview(previous) which i have cached.why?

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES]
```

above code is used to go back to previous view.

EDIT:
this is a brief of my app:I have to retain usernameid throughout the app i,e gng back and forth.
ViewA(login,cached usernameid which i have passed)>viewb>viewc>viewd(usernameid passed as parameter to server)>viewE and
Now I have to go from ViewE(btn click) to ViewB and have to repeat the steps but usernameid is null when reaching from ViewE to ViewB.Due to this my app crashes when reaching viewd as parameter usernameid is null.

Comment: Can you post your destination view controller (previous) code?

Comment: @Asaf: Thnx for commeting.I mean i cached a userid using nsuserdefault and nskeyarchiver.Pushing view,say,from ViewA to View B toViewC i get userid(unarchiving) but when fromViewC to viewA userid is 'null'.

Comment: There no "real" reason for that to happen. I asked the code, because I believe that something is wrong there, and not with the popToViewController command. If you would like, I can try review your code, but you'll have to post it here.

Comment: - (IBAction)scanActn:(id)sender { //previuos view just pushing
    VC*destinationVC=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BandFound"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationVC animated:YES];
 }

Answer (score 0):

Move your method in viewWillAppear, so every time you need to use cached values there should be there, despite navigation between controllers.

Comment: NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *decodedObjects=[userDefaults objectForKey:@"userDetail"];
    self.decodeArray=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:decodedObjects];
  self.profile=[[Profile alloc] init];
  self.profile=[self.decodeArray objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: I have above method in viewwillappear of my View A.And above code [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2(viewA)] animated:YES] in View C